# Issue with repeating static text in Detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *iReport* to make a jrxml file. When I create a file and click on "Launch report wizard" it load some sql query from my database, configured with *iReport*.

I write some static data and also use some image to make a sample pdf file. I write some string in title field and also in column and detail1. Title section show once but value of column header and detail1 repeat many times. My repeated data is equals to the number of data in my table which I load at creation time. How can I stop to repeat my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whatever you write in your detail1  it will repeated until your query ends

Comment: I dont want to repeat my data. So where should I place my content?

Comment: column header like your table header it display all your page,title is the heading of the report it display only in the first page of the report

Comment: Thanks for tour help..
my requirement is to load data from different 2 table. I am newbie in jasper and ireport so, I just want to know that can I make template in ireport and also can I use If-else condition in this. Because I do not see any example related to this?

Comment: you can make template default template also available in ireport .database icon next to preview button click that icon there construct your query

Comment: I have one more problem. I store data as html format in table. When I fetch it, It come with html tag.How can I remove it in ireport.

Comment: database value are in html format,which data u want to extract from the html content