# Input parameters shows twice in jasper report with subreports iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a jasper report that contains three sub-reports. The parameters that I passed to the main report are used in the sub-reports. I didn't show the filter parameters in the header of the main report. I show the filter parameters in the first sub-report. When I go on preview button I have the the filter parameters twice. when I go only on preview on the first report I get the parameters once. Does somebody knows what is the problem?

Comment: Where did you place the *textField* with parameter?

Comment: In the first subreport

Comment: What band did you use?

Comment: Your issue looks like [Issue with repeating static text in Detail band](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17235908/876298)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put others two sub-reports in the first report and the problem was solved.